# gridfstemplate.store(in, url, fileType, metadata); is not storing contentType

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, gridfs

```
 DBObject metadata = new BasicDBObject();
        metadata.put("contentType", "application/pdf");
String fileType = "application/pdf";
int counter=0;
 try (BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new URL(url).openStream(), e)) {
                ObjectId uploaded = gridFsTemplate.store(in, url, fileType, metadata);
                System.out.println(++counter+":"+uploaded.toHexString());
               
            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.error("Error in loading file url["+url+"]");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

I am passing ContentType as both method argument[fileType] and inside metadata a field called contentType.

1. However, inside mongo gridfs contentType is empty.

[image]

Comment: Can you share some code?

Comment: @wak786: Updated.